# nmap ipv6 os scan fails

Tags: ipv6, nmap

When scanning a ubuntu machine with nmap using ipv6 address, nmap cannot determine the os type and only print the os fingerprint.

Although when scanning the same host with ipv4 address it correctly detects it as being linux machine.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: What options are exactly the commands you use when performing this scan? Well Without forgetting that nmap is not able to recognize all operating systems, often by an application may end up getting an OS masked and not be properly scanned!?

Comment: nmap/bin/nmap -oX - -v -O -sT -T Aggressive -p T:22,T:23,T:513,T:139,T:3389,T:137,T:138,T:514,T:1002,T:80,T:443,T:445,T:25 . plus -6 ipv6 when it is the case

Comment: -You can try these options, do not forget that depending on some of the options "mainly fingerprint issue of" any item may end up changing the outcome try use this options here:

I hope it is a good utility ...

nmap -oX -v -sT O -p T:22,23,513,139,3389,137,138,514,1002,80,443,445,25 -6 <IP address here!>

Like I said some items may end up changing the outcome of the fingerprint take a better look more calmly, ok! Anything notify us to succeed there!

Comment: as I mentioned It works for ipv4. could it be the ipv6 network setup?

Comment: Is the target publicly visible? Then I could have a look at it.

Comment: Yes ...
Do I mean yes, because IPv6 is nothing more than an improvement of IPv4, and is more streamlined that "IPv6" is understandable to have differences of fingerprint identification systems over the possible modifications that packets suffer on other tools that act at the address indicated, after a fire wall, packet filters, and other items! You can not be 100% sure of the data that may be returned because of this! But at least he has something about which seems to work better after that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to check for if you can't get a good match. Here's my list:

1. Do you have the latest version of Nmap? We add new fingerprints all the time.
2. Are you giving Nmap the best chance of finding a match? I wrote [an answer over at Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64018/nmap-no-exact-os-matches-for-host-test-conditions-non-ideal-even-with-1-op/64035#64035) that lists a bunch of reasons why Nmap may decide that a fingerprint match isn't reliable.
3. Is there something filtering or modifying packets between you and your target? A firewall or IPS could do this, as well as certain kinds of virtual network interfaces or VPN connections.

Based on the arguments in your comment (`nmap -oX - -v -O -sT -T Aggressive -p T:22,T:23,T:513,T:139,T:3389,T:137,T:138,T:514,T:1002,T:80,T:443,T:445,T:25`) I would recommend adding some UDP port scanning (-sU).

Comment: thank you for your answer. as i mentioned above the os is detected correctly with ipv4. the version of nmap is 6.40.

Comment: @SebastianBrestin The [current version of Nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) is 6.47. IPv4 and IPv6 use completely different fingerprinting engines with separate databases, but the recommendations still apply.

Comment: using "nmap -sU -v -6 -O -T3 -p  U:53,161,162,67,68,65535 ipv6addr" identifies the OS correctly. but when adding -sT and -p  U:53,161,162,67,68,65535,T:22. the TCP/IP fingerprint comes out and no OS match done. Which is the best way to combine does two options?

Comment: it seems like the 22 port is open. if i add a closed tcp port nmap identifies the os correctly.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on AIX 7.1 with "nmap -sU -sT -v -O -T3 -p  U:53,161,162,67,68,65535,T:80,24,22 ipv4" - OS CPE: cpe:/o:ibm:aix:5 cpe:/o:ibm:aix:6 but when scanning over ipv6. no OS match.

Comment: if i lower the tempo si -T1 i get Running (JUST GUESSING): Microsoft Windows XP (13%), IBM AIX 6.X (6%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_xp::sp3 cpe:/o:ibm:aix:6.1
OS fingerprint not ideal because: Scan delay (15000) is greater than 500
No OS matches for host
Network Distance: 2 hops which is slightly better